# NTLM authentication using spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, ntlm

I have a service I want to use in my application. The service uses NTLM authentication for authentication and I am trying to make a REST call with NTLM Auth.

I tried the suggestion in this thread [How to set NTLM authentication in rest template Header in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45811242/how-to-set-ntlm-authentication-in-rest-template-header-in-spring/54913477#54913477)

But it gave me a 500 error (the 401 went away though)

> Only Web services with a [ScriptService] attribute on the class definition can be called from script.

Comment: switch to kerberos, NTLM is outdated : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/docs/current/reference/html/ssk-resttemplate.html

Comment: You wrote a .NET service?  check this if this is the case https://stackoverflow.com/a/10010143/643500 you need to provide more information if you want to get better help

Comment: I did not write the .NET service and dont have nay means to modify it.
Not sure what more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
// IF you want to disable the ssl certification validation

```
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                }
                public void checkClientTrusted(
                        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
                public void checkServerTrusted(
                        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            }
    };
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    String user = "username";
    String password = "password";
    String domain = "domain";  // optional 
    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
            new NTCredentials(user, password, null, domain));

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLContext(sslContext)
            .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory customRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    customRequestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
    RestTemplate build = builder.requestFactory(() -> customRequestFactory).build();
    return build;
}
```